# Sending threaded email from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, email

I've got an app that's sending email from AppEngine, but each email looks like it's a unique message.  Instead I want related emails to be threaded in my email client.  Is there a specific header/format I need to use?

These emails are not necessarily in response to another email, so I don't have a `Message-ID` to plug into `References`.  I've tried using a natural key in `References` and `In-Reply-To` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to thread a list of emails just by using the `In-Reply-To` header with your format `<msg-identifier@host>`.

Supposedly, `msg-identifier` is the identifier to the message you're replying to, but as you're not replying to any message but sending all of them out of thin air, creating a new ID and using it in all the emails you send will also do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using both `References` and `In-Reply-To` with the format `<identifier@systemname>`.  Maybe it'll work with less; I made several changes at once.  If someone chimes in with that kind of detail I'll happily accept their answer instead of mine.